# Default Constructors in Structure Map

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have this code for on ASP.NET MVC website:

```
x.For<AccountController>().TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(() => new AccountController());
```

This code throws a warning which seems quite self explanatory but for some reason when I use the "Use" method it doesn't seem to work. I know I am doing something wrong and would appreciate some help.

The warning is:

Warning 1   'StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Expressions.CreatePluginFamilyExpression.TheDefault' is obsolete: '"Prefer the Use() methods"

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the XMLDoc for the third overload on the  "Use" method, it says this:

> Shorthand to say
>   TheDefault.IsThis(@object)

Therefore, simply do it like this:

```
For<AccountController>().Use(() => new AccountController());
```

Although i'm not sure what the point of this is (injecting a concrete when something requests a concrete), unless this is just an example, and you're really doing something else.

Normally for the MVC Controllers, you create a **ControllerFactory** - i haven't seen a need to "explicitly" inject a concrete Controller.

Comment: Although I wasn't the downvoter, I considered it because your answer is wrong and will have a dramatically different result than what the original code did. Since it is marked as the answer, you should probably edit it to use a lambda, as in my answer.

Comment: Just realized I have edit rights, so I took the liberty of fixing your answer, since it is marked as correct.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're right, what i did was wrong. I didn't consider singletons, as a) i never use them and b) his original code used a singleton anyway, c) thought scoping was 'out of scope' (no pun intended) for this question. Nonetheless, you were more correct (which is why i upvoted you). Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

The direct equivalent of your existing code, but with the new API, is:

```
For<AccountController>().Use(() => new AccountController());
```

This will create a new instance of AccountController any time an instance of AccountController is requested.

**Warning**: If you pass an object instance (as RPM1984 suggests), instead of a lambda, to the Use() method you will get a singleton - the same instance will be returned every time an AccountController is requested. This is very different behavior from what your code was doing previously with the Is.ConstructedBy() syntax.

Comment: +1 - good point on the singleton. Didn't even think of that! I always explicity use `.Singleton()` or `.HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()` before the `.Use` statement. Much safer that way.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, I actually ran into this issue.